# Phonegap Android show titlebar

Tags: android, cordova, titlebar

I am trying to make Phonegap show a titlebar in my Android application. From what I've seen around the net, it should do that by default and people are having trouble actually hiding it - but in my case it is hidden by default and only shows while the app is loading. Once index.html is loaded, titlebar disappears.

This also happens on a blank project created according a tutorial. What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of PhoneGap are you using, and what device/emulator are you seeing this behaviour on? What Android SDK is your target running?

Comment: PhoneGap 0.9.3, tested on HTC Hero (Android 2.1), HTC Wildfire (Android 2.2).

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem using PhoneGap 1.1 and testing with Android Emulator. Seems to be a PhoneGap bug, as no known way of turning titlebar off is working.

Answer (score 0):

hmm try to update the UI with you own layout at "res\layout\main.xml" that way to can include a native toolbar, then below.. you webview (you app) :) good luck!